# Python / IE7 - how to bypass alert boxes

Tags: javascript, python, automation, internet-explorer-7

I have automations scripting written in Python for IE7. It works perfectly, except for the cases when an alert box is triggered. The alert box is triggered in the onload for the body, which means it gets executed before my script gets to it.

I have the following as my wait function, which just hangs until the alert box is clicked:

```
def _waitReady(self):
    """ Waits until IE finishes loading. """
    while self.oIE.Busy: time.sleep(0.1)
    while self.oIE.Document.readyState != "complete": time.sleep(0.1)
```

I would like to simply disable all alert boxes, but it seems IE is incapable of doing so. Alternatively, I was hoping to detect the alert box being open, and then simply perform an action in response (such as simply clicking past it). Are there any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

EDIT:
I know I can cycle through the child windows of IE, and I know I can close the alert box if I can find it.

```
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, function, None) # cycles through child windows
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0) # closes window
```

Now I just need some way of identifying the window as an alert box. Thoughts?

Comment: You could, for instance, try to detect if your waitReady function has hung and fire an 'escape' or 'enter' keypress?

Comment: Can you replace `window.alert()` with your own empty function?

Comment: @jfriend00 - The alert is in the onload method of the body, so it gets executed before I get to it. I would need to modify the HTML before it gets to IE, which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: You don't have to wait for the document to load to replace `window.alert()`.  Just embed a script tag either in the `<head>` section or at the start of the `<body>` and either will execute before the document is loaded.  If you can't modify the document, then you're stuck.  Browsers don't have a switch to disable alerts.

Comment: @Oliver - Any suggestions on how to determine which window to fire the keypress to? I'll need to locate the alert box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue. I ended up simply iterating through every window in the system, checking the class name, and closing the window if it was an alert class (#32770).

I tried to take a more targetted approach, but I couldn't seem to locate the alert window under the IE application.

```
def _waitReady(self):
while self.oIE.Busy:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    waitCount += 0.1

    if waitCount > 5:
        print("killing alert boxes")
        _killAllAlertBoxes()
       waitCount = 0

def _killAllAlertBoxes():
# iterates through all active windows
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(0, _closeWindow, None)

def _closeWindow(hwnd, lparam):
# if window is an alert box (class = '#32770')
if win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd) == '#32770':
    print("Closing Alert Box")
    win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0) # closes window
```

Thanks to those who responded!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for alert windows in firefox, you may need to modify it for IE though.

```
   import time

   time.sleep(2)
   driver.switch_to_alert().accept(); time.sleep(2); time.sleep(2); time.sleep(2);time.sleep(2)
   driver.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: This looks like calls to Selenium, which I am not using. I was hoping for a solution using the IE7 API.. or something similar.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were using Selenium. Good luck trying to find a solution, i'm of no more use!